# Accuracy and Loss Results

Tags: keras, metrics

I got the following results of my convolutional neural network.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mXmY.png)

This is a regression problem, with 2 inputs and 3 output variables. The loss here is `mse` and the metrics is a custom one i have defined.

Can anyone guess what could be the cause of that oscillation in my metrics results around the 450 epoch (don't bother with the test metrics. It's wrong, i will fix it later as soon as i know why the training metrics is oscillating so much)? I'll gladly provide more information if you need (like the definition of the metrics or anything else).

**EDIT**: I am using the code you can see here:

[Original code](https://github.com/sibyjackgrove/CNN-on-Wind-Power-Data/blob/master/CNN_on_power_data_with_Keras_and_Python_generator.ipynb)

I have changed that problem a little bit. I am trying to do a regression instead of the classification the author did there. I've been using Colab, and here's the code i made with some modifications to the original one:

```
# Install tensorflow 2.x in Colab

try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
    pass

# Import libraries  
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

#Power data classification/regression with CNN
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import time as time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydot
import csv as csv
import keras.backend as K
%matplotlib inline
print("TensorFlow version:",tf.__version__)

!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sibyjackgrove/CNN-on-Wind-Power-Data/master/MISO_power_data_classification_labels.csv
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sibyjackgrove/CNN-on-Wind-Power-Data/master/MISO_power_data_input.csv

#Read total rows in csv file without loading into memory
def data_set_size(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
        csv_rows = 0
        for _ in csvfile:
            csv_rows += 1
    print("Numer of rows in csv:",csv_rows)
    return csv_rows-1            #Remove header from count and return

csv_file = "./MISO_power_data_classification_labels.csv"
n_train = data_set_size(csv_file)
print("Training data set size:",n_train)

#Python generator to supply batches of traning data during training with loading full data set to memory
def power_data_generator(batch_size,gen_type=''):
    valid_size = max(1,np.int(0.2*batch_size))
    while 1:
        df_input=pd.read_csv('./MISO_power_data_input.csv',usecols =['Wind_MWh','Actual_Load_MWh'],chunksize =24*(batch_size+valid_size), iterator=True)
        df_target=pd.read_csv('./MISO_power_data_classification_labels.csv',usecols =['Mean Wind Power','Standard Deviation','WindShare'],chunksize =batch_size+valid_size, iterator=True)
        for chunk, chunk2 in  zip(df_input,df_target):      
            InputX = chunk.values       
            InputX = np.resize(InputX,(batch_size+valid_size,24,2,1))
            InputY = chunk2.values
            InputY = np.resize(InputY,(batch_size+valid_size,3))
            if gen_type =='training':
                yield (InputX[0:batch_size],InputY[0:batch_size])
            elif gen_type =='validation':
                yield (InputX[batch_size:batch_size+valid_size],InputY[batch_size:batch_size+valid_size])
            elif gen_type =='inference':
                yield InputX

@tf.function
def nossa_metrica(y_true, y_pred):
  truepotventolow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_true[:,0], 4000), 'int8')
  predpotventolow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_pred[:,0], 4000), 'int8')
  potventolow = K.sum(truepotventolow*predpotventolow)
  truepotventomed = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[:,0], 4000) & K.less_equal(y_true[:,0], 8500), 'int8')
  predpotventomed = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[:,0], 4000) & K.less_equal(y_pred[:,0], 8500), 'int8')
  potventomed = K.sum(truepotventomed*predpotventomed)
  truepotventohigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[:,0], 8500), 'int8')
  predpotventohigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[:,0], 8500), 'int8')
  potventohigh = K.sum(truepotventohigh*predpotventohigh)
  truedesvpadlow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_true[:,1], 1150), 'int8')
  preddesvpadlow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_pred[:,1], 1150), 'int8')
  desvpadlow = K.sum(truedesvpadlow*preddesvpadlow)
  truedesvpadmed = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[:,1], 1150) & K.less_equal(y_true[:,1], 2300), 'int8')
  preddesvpadmed = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[:,1], 1150) & K.less_equal(y_pred[:,1], 2300), 'int8')
  desvpadmed = K.sum(truedesvpadmed*preddesvpadmed)
  truedesvpadhigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[:,1], 2300), 'int8')
  preddesvpadhigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[:,1], 2300), 'int8')
  desvpadhigh = K.sum(truedesvpadhigh*preddesvpadhigh)
  truewlslow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_true[:,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  predwlslow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_pred[:,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  wlslow = K.sum(truewlslow*predwlslow)   
  truewlshigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[:,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  predwlshigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[:,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  wlshigh = K.sum(truewlshigh*predwlshigh)
  return (potventolow+potventomed+potventohigh+desvpadlow+desvpadmed+desvpadhigh+wlslow+wlshigh)/(batch_size*Yclasses)

#Define model using Keras
Yclasses = 3 #Number of output classes
batch_size = 10
valid_size = max(1,np.int(0.2*batch_size))
bias0 =  'zeros'
kernel0 = 'glorot_uniform'

model = keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24,2,1),name='InputLayer'),            
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size=(6,2),strides=(1,1),activation='relu',bias_initializer=bias0,kernel_initializer=kernel0,name='ConvLayer1'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size=(6,1),strides=(1,1),activation='relu',bias_initializer=bias0,kernel_initializer=kernel0,name='ConvLayer2'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="Flatten"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 8,activation='relu',bias_initializer=bias0,kernel_initializer=kernel0,name='FeedForward1'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = Yclasses,bias_initializer=bias0,kernel_initializer=kernel0,name='OutputLayer'),
])
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',verbose = 2,metrics=[nossa_metrica])
model.summary()

train_generator= power_data_generator(batch_size=batch_size,gen_type='training')
valid_generator= power_data_generator(batch_size=batch_size,gen_type='validation')
number_of_batches = np.int32(n_train/(batch_size+max(1,np.int32(0.2*batch_size)))) 
#Training starts
t = time.time()
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch= number_of_batches,epochs=600,validation_data=valid_generator, validation_steps=number_of_batches,verbose=2)
print("Time: %.3f minutes" % ((time.time() - t)/60))
model.save('model.h5')
print("Model Saved")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history['nossa_metrica'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_nossa_metrica'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: very strange. post the code and data

Comment: @makis Ok, done it. It's a bit big.

Comment: Why use `fit` instead of `fit_generator`?

Comment: @emremrah i remember when i started working on this, i had to change that because i was getting an error. I even looked in the internet, and found something about that error in a GitHub page.

Comment: That's weird, are you sure the error isn't from the lack of `fit_generator`?

Comment: Oh, i can't remember anymore, it was a couple months ago. But, do you think that would change anything?

Comment: Well, i tried again with `fit_generator`, didn't got an error, but it takes a lot more time to run than with `fit`. And the problem of oscillation persists with it too, so i'm back to use `model.fit`.